# How to filter out job offers from Bangalore/India in LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

In my LinkedIn account I am a member of many professional groups where different discussions, job ads, etc. are posted.

However I would like to filter out all job ads that come from India, Bangalore etc. (add some regex filter).

Is there anybody who knows how to do it or perhaps offer me some pointers?

Answer (score 4):

LinkedIn will do this for you - no need for regex filters!

On the list of jobs, whether they are within a group or just on the [main LinkedIn job search page](http://www.linkedin.com/jsearch?keywords=programmer&searchLocationType=I&countryCode=us&page_num=1&sortCriteria=R), the checkbox menus on the left side of the screen allow you to filter jobs by location as well as by company, industry, date posted, and many other criteria.

You can either have the location be part of your search criteria: 
[image: search using location as a criteria]

Or you can refine search results with location filters:
[image: refine search results with location]

Do note that these are ways to filter *in* locations, as opposed to filtering them *out*, like you had asked for. However, the second option - filtering existing search results by location - allows you to select multiple checkboxes for your filter. So you could use that sidebar to include all countries and regions *except* India, for example.